# C++ - Randomly select strings without selecting it more than once

Tags: c++, string, random, dictionary

I have a hand full of objects each containing several strings each. Right now its set up as structures each containing a map with keys 1...n, one for each string (`map<int,string> strs`), this can be changed if a better way exists. I need to randomly access all of these str ings without overlapping and know that i'm done. How can I do this, either with the maps or another data structure? Thanks.

Comment: how many times do you need to enumerate those strings in random order? once? lots of times?

Comment: Are all of the strings unique, or can the map in each object contain a string that is also in the map of another object?

Comment: I think you are looking for "shuffle". There are plenty of samples (usually search "shuffle card deck +language" will give you good results)

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::map`? If it's just because you want 1-based indexing instead of 0-based, it would be a lot more efficient to either: (1) just ignore the existence of element 0, or (2) add 1 to the index.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some code for a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> shuffle(std::vector<T> &vect)
{
    std::vector<T> shuffled = vect;
    for(int i = shuffled.size()-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        int idx = rand() % (i+1);
        T tmp = shuffled[idx];
        shuffled[idx] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = tmp;
    }
    return shuffled;
}
```

This will take in a vector, and return a copy of it in a random order. If you have a vector of strings, you can use it like this (I'm using c++11 here):

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::vector<std::string> strs = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "stack", "overflow"};
    for(auto &str : shuffle(strs)) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you're lazy, like me, there's always the random_shuffle() function in `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strs = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "stack", "overflow"};
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd()); // Use a good random number generaor
    std::random_shuffle(strs.begin(), strs.end(), g); // this does the shuffle
    for(auto &str : strs) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to use specify a more robust rng while still using the standard lib for shuffling, use a [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) to prime one of the canned generators (such as [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)), then use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), using your rng as the generator parameter.

Comment: ^ indeed! I'll add it in. :)

Answer (score 0):

A horrible solution, don't do this. Very slow for large candidate vectors, this has n-squared complexity. Shuffling is better, it has linear complexity.

```
std::vector<int> RandomThing(int number, int min, int max)
{
    assert(!"RandomThing" && min < max);
    std::vector<int> candidates;
    for(int i=min; i<max; i++)
        candidates.push_back(i);

    std::vector<int> result;
    for(int i=0; i<number;)
    {
        int candidate_index = rand() % candidates.size();
        result.push_back(candidates[candidate_index]);

        std::vector<int>::iterator it = candidates.begin();
        std::advance(it, candidate_index);
        candidates.erase(it);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just shuffle the candidates vector?  Also, using mod with `rand()` is just bad.

Comment: That's true, much faster to just go through everything once instead of having to remove things from a vector (turning the algorithm into a n-squared one). Sorry about that. Will leave the solution here so people can see a bad way of doing it, but rewrite the text to reflect it's badness. Also regarding rand() % X, the only question is "is it good enough". Sure it has noticeable trends but if that's not a problem then I see no problem.